# I'm don't know why an object cannot be assigned in my constructor function in React?

Tags: reactjs

Short question I hope you can help.

Why does this work?

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.loader;
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.loader = document.getElementById('loaderTest');
    console.log(this.loader);
  }
```

But this does not?

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.loader = document.getElementById('loaderTest');
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    console.log(this.loader);
  }
```

The second method works in vanilla javascript but returns `null` in the console with React. I tried googling but wasn't sure what I was searching for exactly.

What it seems like is that the constructor works before react has rendered any of the component. Am I right in assuming this?

I'm only starting to understand object oriented javascript so if my question is dumb, I apologise.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks
Moe

EDIT: In context

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Site extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.loader;
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.loader = document.getElementById('loaderTest');
  }

  render() {
    return(
        <div id="loaderTest" className="site_container__loader loading block--fullpage">
      </div>
    )
  }
}

module.exports = Site;
```

Comment: What's the relationship between this component and the DOM element with ID `loaderTest`?

Comment: The `loaderTest` div/id is in the same component with the code I posted.

Comment: Then you should reflect that in your example, otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: I've updated the post with the code in context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **constructor** of a React component is executed once the first time the component is instantiated. You should avoid DOM manipulations in contructor as the component is not yet mounted in the actual DOM.

**[Life cycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#constructor) during component initialization(Mounting):**

- constructor(props)

  - The constructor is the right place to initialize state and bind methods
- componentWillMount

  - Invoked Once (client and server)
  - Can change state here with this.setState()  (will not trigger addition render)
  - Called just before render()
- render

  - Component render() is called
- componentDidMount

  - Invoked Once
  - You can do DOM manipulations and other things like API calls etc.
  - Called just after render()

Comment: Thank you. Is that to say that my method of assigning class objects is good practice?

Comment: @Moe-Joe, i dint get what you are trying to say. But from what i understood for the instance properties, putting the declaration in the class body is exactly wrong, because instance properties are per-instance precisely in order to vary from one instance to another. The expression used to initialize an instance need to be in the scope of the constructor.

Comment: I was trying to say: is it good practice to assign the object `this.loader` in the `componentDidMount` function after declaring the `this.loader` object in the constructor?


If not what should I use `refs`? I have read that is not a good idea.

Comment: You have declared this.loader in constructor and initialized in componentDidMount. That is ok and IMO avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively and avoid DOM manipulations. Let React take care of it.